# jQuery button to send parameters not direct to correct URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, parameters, asp.net-mvc-5

I have following button to call the method and send parameters to the method

```
 <input type="button" id="report" data-baseUrl="@Url.Action("ReportExport", "Home")" value="Generate Report" class="btn btn-success submit" />
```

This is script for that

```
$('#report').click(function () {
    // build the url
    var reportUrl = $(this).data('baseUrl') + '?id=' + "PDF" + '&type=' + $('#Type').val() + '&category=' + $('#Category').val() + '&country=' + $('#Country').val() + '&subsidary=' + $('#Subsidary').val() + '&dateHERE=' + $('#Date').val();
    // redirect
    location.href = reportUrl;
});
```

This is controller class

```
 public ActionResult ReportExport(string id, string type, string category, string country, string subsidary, string dateHERE)
 {
         .............    
 }
```

but once I click that button its directing to URL like following

```
http://localhost:49669/Home/undefined?id=PDF&type=002&category=&country=&subsidary=&dateHERE=
```

Its taking undefined controller method instead of  taking correct method,

whats wrong with this approach

Comment: Use single quote `data-baseUrl="@Url.Action('ReportExport', 'Home')"`

Comment: Change it to `$(this).data('baseurl') ` - lower case

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali getting this error `Too many characters in character literal`

Comment: @StephenMuecke thats worked